# How do I separate roles in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my RoR application with Capistrano. Everything was fine until I introduced another role in my Capistrano config, the :web role, which supposedly would be my HTTP/reverse proxy server.

My understanding is that the :app role should refer to the application server (thin, mongrel, whatever) and the :web role should refer to the frontend server (nginx, apache), so I'm rather confused by the choice of running all tasks on all roles, even though capistrano separates them by default.

Right now my problem is that I'm not able to make the deploy:update_code run only on the servers that have an :app role, for example, and capistrano errors out because it tries to run update_code on my web server, where I didn't even install git (I don't need it ...). Has anyone suceeded in doing that? Can someone share the code?

TIA, ngw

Comment: I'm very confused... The documentation about the :web role says "This is assumed to be your web servers (read: Apache / nginx / etc.)" and about the app role says "These are assumed to be your application servers, in a Ruby environment this means something like Mongrel, or Mongrel Cluster; it can also be your Passenger servers.". Why the heck the default is running update_code, symlink, and basically all the deploy in exactly the same way both on :web and :app ? I'm trying to overwrite all the default tasks to run only on :app, but it's a PITA :) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises because the built-in tasks don't respect the role limitations on your custom tasks that invoke them, i.e.,

```
task my_task, :roles => :web do
    run "some command"  # will only be executed on servers with the :web role
    update              # will be executed for all roles
end
```

You will, as you intuited, have to override all the built-in tasks.  Or you can try Rodney Koch's [patch](https://gist.github.com/1300565) to Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly specifying the role in the task name?

```
task :task_A, :roles => :web do
  #do stuff here
end

task :task_B, :roles => :app do
  #do stuff here
end
```